# How to print raw query in class based view in django rest api

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am working on django rest api and using class based views like :

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

   queryset = Users.objects.filter(user_type_id=3)

   def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = self.queryset

       city = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('city', '') 
       if city!="":
            queryset = queryset.filter(work_address__city__icontains=city).distinct()

       return queryset
```

and In url.py file :

```
router.register(r'api/users', views.UsersViewSet)
```

So I want to print raw mysql query in  UserViewSet. So that I can see the query. 
Is it there any method to see the raw query when we would make call "api/users".

Answer (score 3):

You can either install the django debug toolbar:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar

or use:

```
# at the top of the file
from django.db import connection

# and put this before return queryset
connection.queries
```

to output the SQL queries in the log.

Comment: You could add another way; printing the query object like `print queryset.query` where the SQL will show up on whatever terminal you started `runserver`.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer and it is working many thanks. I have also tried print queryset.query and it is showing in terminal great.

Comment: Yes, your solution is straight forward and easier to implement. I always think the complicated way.

Comment: Hi Reiner, I have some other question related django:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182416/giving-error-when-child-class-id-does-not-exist-in-parent-table-in-serializers-c
Please see